# Issue with hash links working with javascript links

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, hash, menu

So my site has dropdown menus in the header that link to child pages of different pages. Like the main button links to `about.php` and the hover menu links to `about.php#contacts` etc...

Now on each of these pages that child pages, they are not seperate pages but are toggled on/off using a javascript function to modify the display css value.

So if I am on index, and click on `about.php#contacts`, the contacts content is displayed just fine. However, if I am on the about page, any link with a hash directing to the about page does not work. To other pages, it will work, but if the hash link points to the current page, it does not work. In the address bar the url changes but I am guessing the page, or the script, needs to be forced to reload to display the new content.

Here is relevant code that I am using, is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
//Drop down
<ul><li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
<ul><li><a href="about.php#profile">contacts</a></li>
//More..
</ul></li></ul>

//Menu on  the page
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:showlayer('contacts');"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
//More
</ul>

//Javascript code that handles everything
<script language="javascript">
var hash = window.location.hash;
var selectedDiv = hash.split('#')[1];
if(selectedDiv != null)
{
    showlayer(selectedDiv);
}
function showlayer(name){
    document.getElementById("contacts").style.display = "none";
    //More
    document.getElementById(name).style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a link that points to the current page with a different hash will not reload the page.

Instead, you need to add a handler to the `hashchange` event and run your code there too.

Better yet, replace your code entirely with the CSS `:target` selector.